# Moving a ball randomly

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, ios4

I am trying to move a ball across the screen with random coordinates . but my object moves just around x axis ! here is my code :

```
 [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
 [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.70];
 [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:1000];
 [UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:YES];

 CGFloat x = (CGFloat) random()/(CGFloat) RAND_MAX;
 CGFloat y = (CGFloat) random()/(CGFloat) RAND_MAX;

 CGPoint squarePostion = CGPointMake(y, x);
 blue3.center = squarePostion;

 [UIView commitAnimations];
```

EDITED :

I change my code to this but doesn't work ~:

```
CGFloat x = (CGFloat) random()/(CGFloat) RAND_MAX * self.view.bounds.size.width;
CGFloat y = (CGFloat) random()/(CGFloat) RAND_MAX * self.view.bounds.size.height;

CGPoint squarePostion = CGPointMake(y, x);
```

same happens !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You scale all your values to 0...1, so I'd expect your ball to actually move to (0,0) and stay there. Also, you might have your x any y coordinates swapped in `CGPointMake`. You need to scale your value to the region you want it to be in. For a random position all over your view (if `blue3` is a subview of `containerView` - which might be self here):

```
 CGFloat x = (CGFloat) random()/(CGFloat) RAND_MAX * containerView.bounds.size.width;
 CGFloat y = (CGFloat) random()/(CGFloat) RAND_MAX * containerView.bounds.size.height;

 CGPoint squarePostion = CGPointMake(x, y);
```

Comment: Please use NSLog(@"%f %f",x,y); and see what values you are actually setting.

Comment: The Console shows me this numbers :     '645.264160 395.960449'

Comment: because my project has created for iPad